# Laravel 4.1 - Sentry 2 User group access/permission

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'am building my project using Laravel 4.1 with Sentry 2 as authorization and authentication package.
I've managed to log users in, register them and assign proper user groups.
I have 3 user groups:

- Administrator
- Presenter
- Registered

I want to achieve 2 things:

1. **Administrators** and **Presenters** can have access to the Administration Panel. **Users** don't.
2. Restrict views in Administration Panel for Presenters. I want them to see only few views (links), for example only **Schedule**.

I've never used roles before and this is first time i use Sentry 2. That's why i'd like to ask for some help. Some point, how to start. How can i achieve both?

Answer (score 4):

For more general permission checks I would look at `inGroup()` helper:

```
// Find the user using the user id
$user = Sentry::findUserByID(1);

// Find the Administrator group
$admin = Sentry::findGroupByName('Administrator');

// Check if the user is in the administrator group
if ($user->inGroup($admin)) {
    // User is in Administrator group
} else {
    // User is not in Administrator group
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define permission for all groups.

check this tutorial https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/helpers

and focus on `hasAccess($permission)` and `hasAnyAccess($permissions)`

Comment: I thought about `hasAccess()` and `hasAnyAccess()`, but i think it's too much of code for a simple project of mine. I thought about something like **if user is in Admin group, than ... do something**.

Comment: I didn't find any other way. I am using the same lengthy process. Apply filter in routes.php and navigation for current user. If you find any easy way, please do post.

Answer (score 0):

in filter.php

```
/**
* hasAcces filter (permissions)
*
* Check if the user has permission (group/user)
*/
Route::filter('hasAccess', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    try {
        $user = Sentry::getUser();
        if( ! $user->hasAccess($value)) {
            if(Sentry::check())
                return Redirect::to('portal')->with('message', 'No Access.');
            else
                return Redirect::to('registration#login')->with('message', 'No Access.');
        }
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
        if(Sentry::check())
            return Redirect::to('portal')->with('message', 'User not found.');
        else
            return Redirect::to('registration#login')->with('message', 'User not found.');
    }
});

/**
* InGroup filter
*
* Check if the user belongs to a group
*/
Route::filter('inGroup', function($route, $request, $value) {
    try {
        $user = Sentry::getUser();
        $group = Sentry::findGroupByName($value);
        if( ! $user->inGroup($group)) {
            if(Sentry::check())
                return Redirect::to('portal')->with('message', 'No Access.');
            else
                return Redirect::to('registration#login')->with('message', 'No Access.');
        }
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
        if(Sentry::check())
            return Redirect::to('portal')->with('message', 'User not found.');
        else
            return Redirect::to('registration#login')->with('message', 'User not found.');
    } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e) {
        if(Sentry::check())
            return Redirect::to('portal')->with('message', 'Group not found.');
        else
            return Redirect::to('registration#login')->with('message', 'Group not found.');
    }
});
```

Routes ->

```
Route::group(array( 'before' => 'Sentry|inGroup:Administrators'), function() {
    Route::get('manageusers', array('as' => 'manageusers', 'uses' => 'UserController@viewUsersList'));
});
```